# New motherboard BSODs and now will not boot

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, bios, cmos

Just built a new computer and placed an old hard drive with windows 7 from it into the new system to boot off. It booted but when Windows started it blue screened. I didn't get the code as the writing was tiny.

Now the computer will not even boot to the splash screen for the motherboard. All components are new and running when it turns on. I have re-seated everything reconnected everything to no avail. Any suggestions would be fantastic.

Comment: You need to give us exact error messages.

Comment: Press F8 at Windows Boot menu and select `Disable Automatic Restart on System Failure`, then post BSOD error code.

Comment: The computer will not boot at all its not possible to do that

Comment: Perform basic trouble shooting (ie: Disconnect everything and see if you can get BIOS beep codes), and come back with specific questions.

Comment: Are you saying you can't get to the BIOS? @techie007 - IMO your comment answers the question. I agree OP needs to come with specific questions but he clearly doesn't know hot to take the next step in debugging!

Answer (score 1):

This is not unusual. The Windows installation on the old hard drive is configured to boot using drivers and configuration from the old motherboard. Startup recovery can often fix this -- boot from a Windows 7 DVD and select it. You can also frequently resolve the problem by changing BIOS settings -- particularly SATA settings such as AHCI/RAID/Emulation options.

Comment: For my own benefit, are you saying that the BIOS is accessible before the motherboard splash screen as I thought it would be the other way round?

Comment: It's usually accessible before and during the motherboard splash screen. He's getting all the way to Windows though, so he should definitely be able to get into the BIOS.

Comment: Thank you, but are you sure he's getting to Windows. I read the OP differently, in that he could, but no more (I have edited the question after you answered to make it readable). However, if the BIOS is accessible before the mobo splash screen, may be it doesn't matter.

Comment: i think you are miss-interpreting basically it wont boot at all anymore

Comment: @Anthony: Clear the CMOS settings and try again. Also, test without the hard drive connected. (Disconnect all devices not needed to get into the BIOS.)